# How is it possible to merge local changes with remote, if some of the new files are present in both? ( git )

Tags: git, github

I created an `xyz.js` file in my local repository. A colleague also created one with the same name.

When I was finished with my work, I tried run the following commands:

```
git shash
git pull
git stash apply
```

I've got an `aborting` message after `git pull`, because `xyz.js` was present both in remote and locally, so I tried this:

```
git stash --all
```

After that I was able to call `git pull`, but I was not able to run `git stash apply` afterwards. I tried to stash it again, and then this:

```
 rm `git ls-tree -r stash@{1}^3 --name-only`
 git stash apply
```

There are a lot of ignored files which are needed to run the project, but some of them are still missing. I tried to fix it, but I just made things worse.

---

I would like to avoid this situation in the future. How should I pull changes and then push my own the right way?

Please do not mark this question as a duplicate. I've found some questions here about asking for which is the preferred way of pull-commit-push, but the answers are not detailed, and they do not mention this problem.

Comment: Are these logically the same file, or are they logically different files?

Comment: In this case the two files are identical, but it may happen, that those files differ

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the stash, I would create a local `dev` branch, because then the full merge conflict resolution will let you fix the problem.

```
git checkout -b dev
git add xyz.js
git commit -m 'adding xyz.js'
git checkout master # or whatever branch you were on
```

Now use your regular git pull or git fetch workflow, possibly with stash. I like fetch best but your stash/pull should work too.

```
git stash 
git pull
```

Then, before applying the stash, you should merge in dev, to apply the new file and fix the merge conflict

```
git merge dev # add --squash to avoid getting a bubble in your tree
# fix conflict and commit
```

And finally you can apply your stash

```
git stash apply
```

**Personal opinion comment**

I generally don't like stash or pull, because they automate more things at the cost of some flexibility.

I always use fetch instead of pull, then inspect what got fetched and merge only if I'm OK with it.

I always use private development branches instead of the stash because then I have full control of how I merge in remote changes, or (more frequently) rebase my private local changes onto the updated master.

My no-pull no-stash workflow is somewhat slower, but I like having the extra control.

Comment: I fully agree with your final assessment about `stash` and `pull`, and let's also note that the slowness factor can be greatly mitigated with a few well-used aliases. I've seen a lot of people in trouble with the consequences of an approximative usage of `stash`, and a temporary branch is so cheap and useful!

Answer (score 1):

To add a bit to [joanis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56309173/1256452), no matter how you go about merging your new `xyz.js` with someone else's also-new `xyz.js`, you're going to hit an "add/add conflict".  Remember that Git's merge engine, no matter how you invoke it—and `git stash apply` and `git stash pop` invoke it, so whether you use `git merge` (this is my own preference) or `git stash` to achieve the merge—takes *three* inputs: a base version, a left-side or "local" or `--ours` version, and a right-side or remote or `--theirs` version.

What Git does is *compare* the base version of the file to your version of the file, to see *what you changed*.  Separately, it compares the (same) base version of the file to their version of the file, to see *what they changed*.

In this particular case, the base version of `xyz.js` is: *The file does not exist.*  The left-side version is your file, and the right-side one is theirs.  (If you swap left and right sides, nothing changes except for the label: `--ours` now means *their* file and `--theirs` now means *your* file.  Since the merge is largely symmetric, you the same conflicts and results.  That's why, at least for cases like this, I just like to call them left and right sides.)  So the *base*, from which your changes sprang, was emptiness.  The base from which their changes sprang was emptiness.  Git always uses a single shared file as the base, so the shared file is this emptiness—and that means that, as far as Git is concerned, it's an "add/add conflict", with all of your lines (creating a file from nothing) conflicting with all of their lines (creating a different version of that file from nothing): Git does not know whether to take your lines, or their lines, or some combination of the two.

It will be up to you, as the person doing the merge, to figure out what to do.  But one of the nice things about having your stuff on your own branch is that you can *abort* the merge and then start over *after* making a new commit.  If your `xyz.js` is completely different from their `xyz.js`, you can, before merging, *rename* your `xyz.js` to, e.g., `iter-xyz.js`.  Make any other necessary changes, commit the result, and *now* you're ready to merge—and there's no add/add conflict at all this time, as your `iter-xyz.js` is added, and their `xyz.js` is added, and the result is that you have both files in your work-tree and in your merge commit.